# QuerySet : TypeError

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this code:

```
>>> d = HotelCheck.objects.filter(client=1,date_booked='2012-02-27').distinct('product').values('product')['product_id']
>>> d
[{'product': 6}, {'product': 1}]
```

And I just want the output to be `1` and `6`.

So I tried this:

```
>>> d = HotelCheck.objects.filter(client=1,date_booked='2012-02-27').distinct('product').values('product')['product_id']
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 153, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError
TypeError
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can show only the values (`6` and `1`,) of the `product`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `values_list`. Pass it the `flat` argument, and you'll directly get a list of product ids. Your lookup is failing because `ValuesQuerySet` can only be sliced or integer indexed.

```
MyModel.objects.values_list('product', flat=True)
# Out: [6, 1]  # this is a ValuesQuerySet that behaves like a list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[x['product'] for x in d]
```

Should give [6, 1].

Answer (score 0):

You're getting back a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary itself. So you need to iterate through them to accumulate what you need--thus John Zwinck's code.